# Yocto imx6 runlevel

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, imx6, runlevel

I have a yocto build for "imx6dl" system, after installing some software ( database/java ) system went into infinite loop during boot : 
"Usage :ps
ps: invalid option --'x' ..." "

I'd like to change run level to "safe mode" in u-boot ( denx ) so I can better diagnose what is causing this, I believe current run level is 5.

How do I change runlevel in uboot ?

Thanks, 
Ran

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if this might help You, but Yocto have mechanism that allows You to run some function while build system has created -http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.4/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND .

Answer (score 1):

In u-boot, you can change kernel arguments by overriding bootargs variable:

```
setenv bootargs '.... 3'
```

You can pass kernel runlevel by appending its number, for example 3.
Then you launch kernel, i.e.

```
bootm
```

Hope it helps